# Laravel Worker doesn't seem to stop

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of jobs in my database, when I run `php artisan queue:work database`, it processes each job but once it processes the last one, it doesn't seem to stop. I thought doing it this way would mean once the worker has no jobs left, it stops.

Comment: You need to provide what you have done so far, we need relating code otherwise we can just guess what may have gotten wrong. So please provide code and more info if possible, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the `--once` option if you want the worker to exit after running one job:

```sh
$ php artisan queue:work --once
```

As of 5.7 you can use `--stop-when-empty` to process all jobs in the queue and then exit:

```sh
$ php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Note: The default behavior changed around Laravel 5.3. Previously a worker would process one job and exit; it only continued running if the `--daemon` option had been used. After 5.3 this became the default behavior, and `--daemon` was deprecated.

Comment: I originally posted my own answer which referenced --stop-when-empty, which I posted before your edit - I prefer your answer overall though so I've deleted mine and will mark yours as accepted.

Comment: My edit was 30 minutes before you posted your answer ;), but it might not have been reloaded on your screen. In any case, thanks

Comment: Ah my bad, yeah that's probably likely!

Answer (score 1):

Note that once the queue:work command has started, it will continue to run until it is manually stopped or you close your terminal. Using the --once option will not resolve your problem.
Check laravel documentation for more.

The documentation says: The --once option may be used to instruct the worker to only process a single job from the queue.